# Using jQuery load() event for fading images (instead of plain JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, this, target

I wrote this code in JavaScript to make the images of my website fading in when loaded:

```
function loaded(e){
    var target = e.target;
    target.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

I'm calling the function via HTML attribute `onload` and it works just fine....

Now, I'm trying to do the same, but now using the `load()` jQuery event, just to avoid calling the function from the HTML attribute. So I wrote:

```
$('img').load(function(event){
    $(this).css('opacity', "1");
});
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Why?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: Your question seems to assume that JavaScript and jQuery are on the same level, which is absurd. You know that jQuery (a library) is *written in* JavaScript (a programming language), right?

Comment: Yep I perfectly know and understand it but i don't see what is the relation with my question.

Comment: The relevance is that your question, as stated, is **inadequate to this site**. Remember, we are not here to simply "answer you"; using stackoverflow.com is a privilege, and therefore you should comply to the site rules (like [asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [accepting useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and so forth).

Comment: Ok, I don't see what is wrong in my question. If it's bothering you why do you care. Just pass your way, your remark is not interesting at all.

Comment: Now you are being offensive. You know, I'm trying to help you: better questions usually get better answers. Also, being polite usually helps, too.

Comment: I did not notice that you were helping me or were answering any questions, I don't see any offence in my answers either. You're not even able to explain why my question "is inadequate to this site". I'm just asking a web programming question on a community website made for this purpose, your answer is about website policy. So once again and with entire respect if my question bothering you just pass your way and don't waste my time, please.

Comment: I agree with you: you are, indeed, unable to notice much, if anything at all. But don't be upset, I will save you from losing more time, and fix your question myself ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing my question yourself, that was very helpful... Have a good one mate!

Comment: Again, I am not doing that (only) for you.

Comment: Just don't do it only for you. But I think there is no way to be agree with each other so maybe we could stop this useless conversation. So if you wish to help me (and the others users who are wondering the same question) it would be appreciate, if not I'm not part of this discussion  anymore. Have a good one.

Comment: Useless? Well, you *did* edit your question at the end, didn't you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
img {opacity: 0.25;}
```

And after the page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").css("opacity", 1);
});
```

Comment: As my website has a lot of pictures, i don't want to wait that the document is entirely loaded to load the pics. it takes almost 1min.

Comment: i did not try it but it works for sure but it's not what i'm looking for